# Algorithm for bisecting a set of points using a circle of fixed radius

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Suppose I have a set of points in the Cartesian plane, defined by an array/vector of (X,Y) coordinates. This set of points will be "contiguous" in the coordinate plane, if any set of discontinuous points can be contiguous. That is, these points originated as a rectangular grid in which regions of points were eliminated by a prior algorithm. The shape outlined by the points is arbitrary, but it will tend to have arcs for edges.

Suppose further that I can create circles of fixed radius `r`.

I would like an algorithm that will find me the center `X,Y` for a circle that will enclose as close to exactly half of the given points as possible.

Comment: Your question is underspecified.  We don't know, for example, the distribution of the points; are they distributed randomly throughout a field that is rectangular?  In order to encapsulate half the points, we would need to know what the outer boundary of the field looks like.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Added details. Please let me know if still not clear.

Comment: Well, you're basically talking about the area of a circle, pi r squared, where the units is the distance between two points in your coordinate plane. Plug in the area, and solve for `r`.  I'm not sure why the center of the circle is relevant; so long as the circle is the right size, you should be able to place it anywhere inside the plane, and it should capture roughly the same number of points, assuming (as you say) that the points are evenly distributed throughout the plane.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: r is fixed - this makes it interesting !

Comment: Then I don't...  Why would the position of the circle matter?

Comment: @RobertHarvey because the position is the only variable - we must "solve for position", which is interesting on non-continuous functions as "is inside the circle"

Comment: I think you should ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com first, since, unless you're willing to entertain some technique like Monte Carlo simulation, this is basically a math problem.  Probably an integral.

Comment: Observation #1: In **all** cases the solution count is infinite

Comment: @EugenRieck: Not really.  If you change the distribution of the points so that the density of the points increases or decreases in both the X and y directions, you can achieve a single-point solution.

Comment: Observation #2: In at least some cases, the set of solution points is not convex.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: As we have discreet points, but a continuous plane for the center, ther will allways exist a variation of the center, that does not change the count of points enclosed (Mule paradoxon)

Comment: @EugenRieck: I don't have the math chops for it, but if I did, I could write a proof that, if the density of the points increases in the X direction, and the density of the points increases in the Y direction, that there exists a circle located on a single point on the plane which encompasses the exact number of points asked for. And if I'm wrong, there's still only a small area in which that circle can move and still contain that exact number of points.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes - but there exists an infinite amount of others, with a center very close to the one you mean.

Comment: @merlin2011 Will the shape covered by the points allways be bigger than the circle?

Comment: @EugenRieck, No, but it is perfectly acceptable for only part of the circle to be utilized in enclosing half the points.

Comment: @merlin2011  You're kidding, right?  Well, now you've made the solution very complex.

Comment: No! This is the reason why I asked - the center of the circle might very well lie nearly up to `r` outside the shape

Comment: Alright, well if this is to stay on Stack Overflow, I have to ask: 1.  What have you tried so far, and 2.  Does this have any practical programming concerns, or is it just a homework problem or an amusing puzzle?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Apologies if I wasn't clear. All I am saying is that that large areas of the circle can include no points, as long as close to half the points are in the circle.

Comment: AI in game development? Weapon with an effective radius of `r` should affect half of a population?

Comment: (Simulation) Mission control for search & rescue where you only have a fixed amount of fuel to fly around and take radar scans for beacons, so I want to eliminate as many points as possible out of the candidate set with a single scan.

Comment: Quite similar ... by being opposite. Gimme a minute, I think I am getting somewhere

Comment: In terms of what I've tried. I have tried other algorithms to eliminate points with moderate degrees of effectiveness but I want to do a binary search if possible.

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this (sorry if I have very bad wording: I didn't learn my Maths in english)

Step 1: Find axis

- For all pairs of points, **that are less than 2r apart** calculate how many points lie on either side of the connecting line
- Chose the pair with the **worst** balance
- Calculate the line, that bisects these two points as an axis ("Axis of biggest concavity")

Step 2: Find center

- Start on the axis far (>2r) away on the side, that had the lower point count in step 1 (The concave side)
- Move the center on the axis, until you reach the desired point. This can be done by moving up with a step of sqrt(delta), where delta is the smallest distance between 2 points in the set, if overreaching move back halfing the step, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the algorithm for [smallest enclosing circle of a point set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_circle_problem).

A somewhat greedy algorithm would be to simply remove points 1 at a time until the circle radius is less or equal to r.